# Как настроить мультимаршрут, чтобы он не строился по платным дорогам?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

В своем приложении на API Яндекс.Карт (на JavaScript) пользуюсь построением мультимаршрута (`ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute`) по точкам:

```
route = new ymaps.multiRouter.MultiRoute({
    referencePoints: data.new_coords,
    params: {
        results: 1
    }
}, {
        avoidTrafficJams: true
    }
);
```

Проблема в том, что маршрут строится по платным дорогам, например, маршрут Тверь - Солнечногорск - Королев прокладывается через платную трассу М-11:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как настроить мультимаршрут, чтобы он не строился по платным дорогам?

Answer (score 3):

В API нет настройки, которая позволила бы избегать платные дороги на маршруте, но в ответе маршрутизатора есть флаг `hasTolls`, который показывает их наличие, и среди 3-х лучших альтернатив одна будет без платных дорог, если это возможно.

Кроме того, вы можете указывать via-точки, чтобы маршрут прошел через нужную вам дорогу.

Comment: А случайно в предлагаемых Яндексом альтернативных маршрутах нет флага, указывающего, что именно эта альтернатива платная, а другая - бесплатная?

Comment: Для каждого маршрута в ответе есть флаг hasTolls, который принимает значение true (маршрут с платными участками) или false (на маршруте нет платных участков)

Comment: А можно как-нибудь выводить самый короткий маршрут и который имеет флаг `hasTolls=true`?

Comment: Вы можете это напрограммировать сами. Готовых методов в API нет, как написала в исходном ответе. Обратите внимание, что `hasTolls=true` означает, что на маршруте **есть** платные дорого